# jQuery: how to set fixed decimals for input field value

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, numbers, format

I have a basic input field in which an amount is to be filled in. 
The field is formatted as text as it also has to work with older browser versions.

Is there a way I can use jQuery and/or Regex to set fixed decimals (2) to any number in this field ?

I tried the following but this doesnt change anything:

```
<input type="text" class="span6" id="amount" maxlength="12" name="amount" />

$('#amount').on('blur', function() {
    var amount = $('#amount').val().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    if( ($('#amount').val() != '') && (!amount.match(/^\d+$/) ) {
        $('#amount').val( amount.toFixed(2) );
    }
});
```

What I am looking for is a way to add two decimals to the input value if there are none and the input is a number.

**Examples:**

- 1000 should become 1000.00
- 1000.99 should stay 1000.99 as there are already two decimals.

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Comment: if statement has missing paranthesis `)`

Comment: Thanks - this was just missing here in the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a fiddle, please check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/madhust/MEELE/)

before using `toFixed` convert the `amount` to integer `parseInt(amount)`.

**Edit**

**Code**

```
$('#amount').on('blur', function() {
var amount = $('#amount').val().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
if( ($('#amount').val() != '') && (!amount.match(/^$/) )){
    $('#amount').val( parseInt(amount).toFixed(2));
}
 });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! The link is currently not working for me. Could you post the code here ?

Comment: Thanks ! Wouldn't parseInt cut off decimals if my input value already had them ? If there are already decimals then I would need to keep them.

Comment: Yes it will cut off the decimals if you want decimals to retain then use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`

Comment: This works. One last question: If I have text as the input it now changes this to NaN. Is there a way I can just leave it unchanged if the input is text and otherwise do what you have ?

Comment: I got this sorted. Everything works perfect now. Thanks again for the quick help !